# Flask catch-all endpoint no longer working when app deployed on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The my other endpoints are working correctly, but when my catch-all endpoint for the prefix /static/ is no longer working and 404s are being returned. This works locally, but once deployed to AWS Beanstalk I am running into these issues.

Flask endpoint:

```
@application.route('/')
@application.route('/static/<path>', strict_slashes=False)
@cross_origin()
def main_static(*args, **kwargs):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I tried implementing a catch for 404s, but that did not solve the issue either:

```
@application.errorhandler(Exception)
@cross_origin()
def main_404(*args, **kwargs):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Can you please show the definition for the /courses endpoint?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part - I meant /static

Comment: The idea is my Angular app handles all the routing, so I just want to forward all endpoint requests to the Angular app (packaged and in the static folder)